# Haskell is not lazy when evaluating conditions

Tags: haskell

I was expecting haskell to evaluate `exits` and `hasPerms` only when needed. But the code below throws an Exception: *getPermissions:getFileStatus: does not exist (No such file or dir
ectory)*.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-missing-signatures #-}

import System.Directory
import System.Exit (exitWith, ExitCode (ExitFailure, ExitSuccess))

main = do
    let filename = "test.txt"
    exists <- doesFileExist filename
    hasPerms <- hasPermission filename

    if | not (exists && hasPerms) -> exit
       | otherwise -> return ()

    doSomethingWithFile filename

hasPermission filename = do
    perms <- getPermissions filename
    return $ readable perms && writable perms

doSomethingWithFile _ = return ()

exit = System.Exit.exitWith $ ExitFailure 1
```

If I write it in another way, it works just fine.

```
main = do
    let filename = "test.txt"
    exists <- doesFileExist filename
    if exists then do
        hasPerms <- hasPermission filename
        if hasPerms then
           return ()
        else
            exit
    else
        return ()

    doSomethingWithFile filename
```

I am expecting the compiler to **not** evaluate `hasPerms` if `exists` is `False`, since the value of `not (exists && hasPerms)` will always be `True` if `exists` is `False`.

Is my understanding of lazy evaluation wrong, or do I have to enable a compiler flag or haskell extension?

Comment: Have you tried to desugar the do notation? Perhaps it will help clear up the situation.

Comment: A historical note: the `IO` interface was invented exactly to avoid the kind of "laziness" you are describing.

Comment: You can still opt back into laziness with [unsafeInterleaveIO](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeInterleaveIO). This is rarely the right decision, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
doesFileExist filename
```

This is an `IO Bool`. That's an `IO` action waiting to happen. It's lazy, like everything else in Haskell. Just uttering the phrase `doesFileExist filename` does *not* call out to the OS in Haskell. That's the crux of our non-strict semantics. However, you didn't just utter the phrase. You did something much more specific: you bound it with `<-`.

```
exists <- doesFileExist filename
```

`exists` is of type `Bool`. That Boolean is still lazy, to the extent that it's meaningful for it to be. `exists` might still be a thunk waiting to be evaluated in some form. *However,* note that the `IO` part is gone. `exists` is a `Bool`, not an `IO Bool`. The `IO` part happened the moment we said `<-` and bound a variable inside the `IO` monad. The `IO` part is the part that actually calls out to the system and does the "real world" work. And we forced that the moment we bound the variable (Technically, we forced the side effect as soon as we forced the `IO` computation for our `main` to run, but that's semantics).

This is a key difference between `<-` and `let` in a `do` block. `let` inside a `do` block is just like `let` anywhere else. It's a rename and nothing more. But `<-` isn't just a rename. It does work. It does actual work inside the monad, and that work has to be done in order.

As you've already found out, you want the `hasPerms <- hasPermission filename` line inside the `if` statement. What you want is for the *effect* of checking the permission to only happen conditionally, so that work (and the accompanying `<-` which desugars to a `>>=` call) needs to be done inside the `if` statement.